# Membership.GetUser or Profile.GetProfile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

Whats the different between Membership.GetUser and Profile.GetProfile if i wants to return a specific users information?

Comment: Please don't add "c#, asp.net" to your titles. That's what we have tags for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwzxkby7.aspx) and [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profileprovider.aspx) are two completely different things.  The Membership.GetUser providers authentication for an application and designates if the user is logged in, while the Profile is something that can be used to describe a user given properties that have been defined in the web.config that are type safe and customized for an applicaiton.

**EDIT:**
To follow up a little more, a User object that is returned from Membership.GetUser() has information like username, password, security question / answer.

Profile information can contain anything that you want to know about a user, such as first name, last name, DOB, favorite type of ice cream, etc.  Just as long as you set this up in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <profile>
        <properties>
            <add name="firstName" type="string"/>
            <add name="lastName" type="string"/>
            <add name="DOB" type="DateTime"/>
            <add name="favoriteIceCream" type="string"/>
        </properties>           
    </profile>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Can you say that Membership.GetUser get information from the database and Profile.GetProfile receive information from the Property's inserted in the web.config?

Comment: no because the profile information is mainly stored in the database per user as well.

Answer (score 2):

The membership is the username, password and optionally a secret question / answer. You get a `MembershipUser` back from `Membership.GetUser()`.

The profile is your own customised profile object that you can configure to store whatever information you want in it.

Comment: Can you say that Membership.GetUser get information from the database and Profile.GetProfile receive information from the Property's inserted in the web.config?

Comment: they both come from the database. With the profile you can use the web.config to define which properties should be stored but when you put data into them via the profile API they are stored in a database.

Answer (score 1):

`Membership.GetUser` will return the user entry - e.g. the user with name, first name, e-mail address and so on.

`Profile.GetProfile` will return a given user's profile settings, e.g. his preferences, config settings etc.

Comment: Can you say that Membership.GetUser get information from the database and Profile.GetProfile receive information from the Property's inserted in the web.config?

Comment: @Thomas Bolander: no the profile information is stored in SQL Server, too - by default. Certainly not in `web.config`...